# Include .h file from a pod into a different pod in the same xcworkspace

Tags: ios, cocoapods, yapdatabase

I have two pods in my project : 
One, is `YapDatabase` for key-value storage. 
 
Two, is `APAddressBook` to deal with phonebook.

I want to extract phonebook contacts as `APContact` objects then store them in `YapDatabase`. 

The Problem is `YapDatabase` wants the object to save to be serialised using its own way (Being a subclass).

I want to modify my `APContact` to be a subclass of `YapDatabaseObject` but they are in two different pods.

How, can i import `OTRYapDatabaseObject.h` into `APContact` without the error `"OTRYapDatabaseObject.h" file not found` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The YapDatabase project does not enforce a base class. That is, there is no such thing as `YapDatabaseObject`, at least in the sense that it is not a part of the official API.

The only requirements that YapDatabase itself enforces, is that the configured `serializer` & `deserializer` are able to convert your object to & from data blobs.

The wiki article "Storing Objects" has more information on this:
https://github.com/yapstudios/YapDatabase/wiki/Storing-Objects

But the gist is that YapDatabase has a configurable `serializer` & `deserializer`, and you can customize them to fit your needs.

```
typedef NSData* (^YapDatabaseSerializer)(NSString *collection, NSString *key, id object);
typedef id (^YapDatabaseDeserializer)(NSString *collection, NSString *key, NSData *data);
```

> I want to extract phonebook contacts as APContact objects then store them in YapDatabase

It looks like [APContact](https://github.com/Alterplay/APAddressBook/blob/e089e8a05d0340be158b9a52cb99d21b3606ac82/Pod/Core/Public/Models/APContact.h) is a pretty basic NSObject, consisting of only public properties. So to achieve your goal, all you really need is code (within your project) that can perform the serialization & deserialization of APContact objects. And then tweak YapDatabase's serializer & deserializer to use your custom APContact serialization & deserialization when appropriate.